# Problems with displaying the correct number of items in an has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `UseCases` (about 6.000 rows) and `EducationalObjectives` (about 4.000 rows) associated with `has_and_belongs_to_many`(`EducationalObjectivesUseCases` with about 8.000 rows). Some of the EducationalObjectives belong to subjectA (about 4.500 rows in `EducationalObjectivesUseCases`) and some to subjectB (about 3.500 rows in `EducationalObjectivesUseCases`).

Now I want to display a list of all UseCases which are tied to the EducationalObjectives of the subjectA which should be about 3.500 rows but I get about 4.500 rows (you've guessed it: the number of associations within `EducationalObjectivesUseCases`) since duplicate entries (UseCases with many EducationalObjectives on subjectA) are displayed the number of times of entries.

My thinking was that I only can tell through the HABTM association that I need the UseCases for subjectA but don't know how the avoid duplicate entries.

```
class UseCase < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :educational_objectives
end

class EducationalObjective < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :use_cases
end

class EducationalObjectivesUseCase < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :educational_objective
  belongs_to :use_case
end


class UseCasesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @use_cases = UseCase.all.
                    order(:use_case).
                    joins(:educational_objectives).
                    where('educational_objectives.subject_id = ?',2)
    end
end
```

How do I get Rails to display only the used UseCases for subjectA once (only 3.500 rows)? Where is my mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way to solve this is to call *#distinct* on the *where*-chain. Since the *select* is automatically set to `use_cases.*` this will work and filter out duplicated records.

```
def index
  @use_cases = UseCase.joins(:educational_objectives)
                      .where(educational_objectives: {subject_id: 2})
                      .order(:use_case)
                      .distinct
end
```

Alternatively this can be solved using a sub-query.

```
def index
  educational_objectives = EducationalObjective.where(subject_id: 2)

  use_case_ids = EducationalObjectivesUseCase
                   .where(educational_objective_id: educational_objectives)
                   .select(:use_case_id)

  @use_cases = UseCase.where(id: use_case_ids).order(:use_case)
end
```

**edit**

The sub-query code will execute 1 SQL query, just like the code for the distinct version. When executed on the console suffix each statement with `;nil` to prevent execution by the *#inspect* method (used to show you the result). If you don't do this the console will try to show the result and trigger the query before we are ready executing it. It will still work, but it looks like it are multiple queries.